# Ressource editor in IntellIJ doesn't show a references to class code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx, resources, intellij-plugin

I opened this  [github]https://github.com/00-Evan/shattered-pixel-dungeon) repository as project in Intellij, then i go to assets to resoursces, then i open  text resource files .properties. This project uses libGDX. After that  when i open any .properies file in a resource folder via resource editor then Intellij doesn't show any referneces to classes where that resource text was used and mark it as unused resources(actually it used in classes).

[image: one of .properties files. all 2k lines marked as unused by intellij]

[image: A plugin that used for editing resources]

Here is usage of  resource lines accesed from that .propeties file in class.

```
@Override
    public String info() {
        String info = desc();

        if (volume == 0){
            info += "\n\n" + Messages.get(this, "desc_water");
        } else {
            info += "\n\n" + Messages.get(this, "desc_heal");
        }

        if (isFull()){
            info += "\n\n" + Messages.get(this, "desc_full");
        }

        return info;
    }
```

I tried to update resource editor plugin and  own intellij, but nothing changed. Tried to google similar problems, but found noting.
Excpeted that intellij will show a reference to classes in .properties files.

Answer (score 0):

After cloning and reading the code https://github.com/search?q=repo%3A00-Evan%2Fshattered-pixel-dungeon+desc_water&type=code

```java
@Override
    public String info() {
        String info = desc();

        if (volume == 0){
            info += "\n\n" + Messages.get(this, "desc_water");
        } else {
            info += "\n\n" + Messages.get(this, "desc_heal");
        }

        if (isFull()){
            info += "\n\n" + Messages.get(this, "desc_full");
        }

        return info;
    }
```

but the key is `items.waterskin.desc_water`, if you change the key to the same, it somehow could find a usage.

The Messages class is `com.shatteredpixel.shatteredpixeldungeon.messages.Messages`, IDEA can't parse so complex logic to assume there are prefixes added, as it's a static code analyzer, it doesn't try to compile and evaluate any class file at the coding stage due to performance issue and robust(if some code is wrong, it still try to get the right relations between strings and classes).

This may not be a good answer, the resource editor still has other issues.

Comment: So, i should remove prefixes? In this case, will  IDEA  show a references?

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't work, it only tries to link strings like this:

bundles.get(0).get("items.waterskin.desc_water");